# How to pass authentication in spring test case

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot 1.5.6 with OAuth 2.0. The problem is that when I run below test case, I get Null pointer exception on below line for authentication object.

```
 System.out.println(authentication.getName());
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource( locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
public class ProfileControllerTest {

......
......

     @Before
      public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
        ...........
        .........
      }

      @Test
      public void profileTest() throws Exception {
        String userId = "12345678";

        mockMvc.perform(get("user/" + userId + "/profile"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
      }
}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "user/{userId}/profile",
      method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getProfile(
      @PathVariable(value = "userId", required = true) String userId,
      HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
      System.out.println(authentication.getName());
    }
```

**Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String OAUTH_COOKIE = "OAUTH-ACCESS-TOKEN";

  private UserService userService;
  private OAuth2TokenAuthenticationFilter ssoFilter;
  private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

  /**
   * WebAppSecurity overloaded constructor.
   */
  public WebAppSecurityConfig(UserService userService,
      OAuth2TokenAuthenticationFilter ssoFilter,
      JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.ssoFilter = ssoFilter;
    this.accessTokenConverter = accessTokenConverter;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/logout-success")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(ssoFilter,
            AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class).logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll()
        .deleteCookies(OAUTH_COOKIE);
  }

  @Autowired
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    configure((DefaultAccessTokenConverter) accessTokenConverter
        .getAccessTokenConverter());
  }

  protected void configure(DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter) {
    DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter =
        new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
    userTokenConverter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userTokenConverter);
  }

  @Override
  protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userService;
  }
```

How to pass Authentication object in above test case?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@WithMockUser` annotation on your test.

For example:

```
  @Test
  @WithMockUser(username = "admin", roles = { "ADMIN" }) 
  public void profileTest() throws Exception {
    String userId = "12345678";

    mockMvc.perform(get("user/" + userId + "/profile"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
  }
```

Assuming you have spring-security configured and enabled for the `"user/" + userId + "/profile"` endpoint then  `System.out.println(authentication.getName());` in your controller will print: `admin`.

More details in the [Spring Securty docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser).

Comment: After adding @WithMockUser, I am still getting null pointer exception

Comment: I suspect you don't have spring-security configured and enabled for the `"user/" + userId + "/profile"` endpoint. What happens when you run your application i.e. a _real_ run rather than a test run ... is Authentication null then too? If so, then the issue isn't with `@WithMockUser`. Either way, it's impossible to diagnose what's wrong given the information we have so far. Could you update your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's currently missing your pom.xml and your confoguration of Spring Security ...

Comment: I have updated the original question where you can see that security is  enabled for the `"user/" + userId + "/profile"`. Application is actually using OAuth 2.0 and Single Sign On feature.  It works fine in real run.